# Pandas dataframe: using the output of a function in row x as input for the same function in row x+1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe that looks as follows

```
SIM              Sim_1       Sim_2                                
2015          100.0000    100.0000
2016          2.504613    0.123291   
2017          3.802958   -0.919886       
2018          4.513224   -1.976056      
2019         -0.775783    3.914312
```

The following function

```
df = sims.shift(1, axis = 0)*(1+sims/100)
```

returns a dataframe which looks like this

```
SIMULATION       Sim_1       Sim_2         
2015         NaN          NaN         
2016        102.504613  100.123291     
2017          2.599862    0.122157      
2018          3.974594   -0.901709
```

The value in 2016 is exactly the one that should be calculated. But the value in 2017 should take the output of the formula in 2016 (102.504613 and  100.123291) as input for the calculation in 2017. Here the formula takes the original values (2.599862 and 0.122157)
Is there a simple way to run this in pyhton?

Comment: If you can come up with a vectorized formula then yes, otherwise you'll need a loop. Something like `(1 + df['Sim_1']/100).cumprod()` perhaps?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You can probably use for loop and calculate the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to show the growth of 100 given subsequent returns.  Your problem is that the initial `100` is not in the same space.  If you replace it with zero (0% return) then do a `cumprod`, your problem is solved.

```
sims.iloc[0] = 0
sims.div(100).add(1).cumprod().mul(100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more question: Is there a way to do the same calculation backwards , e.g. calculate the single return in every period from the cumprod in the dataframe above?

Comment: @Carmen look up pct_change

Answer (score 0):

Just a crude way of implementing this:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
  try:
    df2['Sim1'][i] = float(df2['Sim1'][i]) + float(df2['Sim1'][i-1])
    df2['Sim2'][i] = float(df2['Sim2'][i]) + float(df2['Sim2'][i-1])
  except:
    pass
```

There may be a better way to optimize this.